# Hashbytes comparison in stored proceduring not matching record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

The password field in my user table (SQL Server 2008) is encrypted using `HASHBYTES` on insertion.  I have a stored procedure with parameters for the username and plain-text password which does a `SELECT` using that username and the password sent through `HASHBYTES`, then returns the user record if it finds a match.  The SP is always returning an empty recordset, but if I copy and paste just the `SELECT` from the SP to a new query window, it returns the matched record.  There're no other statements in the SP. I'm missing something here; what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the SELECT on its own works, but inside the procedure it does not, the first thing I would look for is parameter types. Hash will vary wildly on similar input, but different types:

```
select hashbytes('MD5','Lorem Ipsum'), hashbytes('MD5',N'Lorem Ipsum')
```

Comment: Thanks. The real problem is I was trying to query a record that I had set via an INSERT statement and I hadn't specified unicode. I updated the record and now it works.

Comment: By the way, I used the word "encrypted" out of convenience when I guess I should have used "hashed". Mistake acknowledged.

Comment: We got burned because we were storing and MDF hash in a column of type NVARCHAR(MAX). The line of code was `byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input).` ASCII needed to be changed to UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

How are you passing in the parameters when calling it from your code?  Are there any embedded CR/LF or whitespace?

Comment: Maybe, but I doubt it. I've tried this both via code (ASP.NET C#) using command parameters, and using the Execute Stored Procedure function in SSMS. Same results for both.